# Loop to Fill Down to Next Specified Value and Repeat

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have qualitative values in column A and quantitative values in column B associated with them.

I want to look for a specific value in column A, starting with A1. Once the value is found, I want to fill the value associated with it in column B down to the last row before the next value is found in column A. I want to repeat this until no more data is available in column A.

I have tried a number of formulas, but I think a VBA loop might be needed since I have nearly 25,000 rows.

Below is a visualization of what I am trying to do, looking for "W" and filling down. I greatly appreciate any thoughts or ideas!

[image][image]

Comment: You will need VBA since you want to replace existing values with new ones (22, in your example) Edit: or use formulas in a helper column

Comment: In cell C1, `=B1`. In cell C2, `IF(A2="W",B2,C1)` and fill down. Then copy C as values to column B.

Comment: Hi old friend, @BigBen

Answer (score 1):

### Fill Down Column With Matched Value

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateColumn()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FirstRowAddress As String = "A1:B1" ' at least two columns!
    Const sStringColumn As Long = 1
    Const dNumberColumn As Long = 2
    Const CriteriaString As String = "W"
     
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet 'improve!
    
    ' Declare variables referenced or calculated
    ' in the following With statement.
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    ' Reference the range ('rg') and write its number of rows
    ' to a variable ('rCount').
    With ws.Range(FirstRowAddress)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data in range.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        rCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    ' Write the values from the range to a 2D one-based array,
    ' the source array ('sData').
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = rg.Value
    
    ' Define the 2D one-based one-column destination array ('dData').
    Dim dData() As Double: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Declare variables to be used in the following For...Next loop.
    Dim sString As String
    Dim dValue As Variant
    Dim dNumber As Double
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Write the required values from the source array to the destination array.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sString = CStr(sData(r, sStringColumn))
        If StrComp(sString, CriteriaString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
            dValue = sData(r, dNumberColumn)
            If VarType(dValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                dNumber = CDbl(dValue)
            Else ' is not a number
                dNumber = 0
            End If
        'Else ' is not equal; do nothing (use current number)
        End If
        dData(r, 1) = dNumber
    Next r
    
    ' Reference the destination range ('drg').
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Columns(dNumberColumn)
    
    ' Overwrite the destination range values with the required values
    ' from the destination array.
    drg.Value = dData

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Column updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you need this could fit

```
Sub test()
    Dim LR As Long, Rng As Range, StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long, StartVal, c
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, 1))
    
    Set c = Columns(1).Find("W", after:=Cells(LR, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            StartRow = c.Row
            StartVal = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Set c = Rng.FindNext(c)
            EndRow = IIf(c.Row > StartRow, c.Row, LR)
            Range(Cells(StartRow + 1, 2), Cells(EndRow - 1, 2)) = StartVal
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End Sub
```